# cocos2d : running different actions on parent and child node

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have `CCNode *parentNode`, that has `CCNode *childNode1` and `CCNode *childNode2`. I'm trying to move parentNode with `CCMoveTo` action, but leave `childNode2` oh the same position.

The following code

```
[parentNode runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.5f position:ccp(x, y)]];
[childNode2 runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.5f position:ccp(-x, -y]];
```

doesn't help me to achieve my goal.

Is it even possible to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's possible. Your problem is that the parent and the child have different coordinate systems and consequently `x` and `y` variables are not the same for them. I'm sure that the parent moves to the correct location whereas the child doesn't. So what you need is to calculate correct `x` and `y` values for the child.

Or you can use `CCMoveBy`. It would look like this:

```
float x_diff = x - parentNode.position.x;
float y_diff = y - parentNode.position.y;

[parentNode runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.5f position:ccp(x, y)]]; 
[childNode2 runAction:[CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:0.5f position:ccp(-x_diff, -y_diff)]];
```

Comment: Oh, i used coordinates converting. Bug I doesn't help. Actually, ```[childNode2 runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.5f position:[parent convertToNodeSpace:CGPointZero]];``` not moving child to {0; 0}. Can't figure out, why so.

Comment: you mean it doesn't move the child to {0, 0} in PARENT's coordinate system?

Comment: Yes, to parent's {0, 0}. Oh, I think i see the problem. It calculates new position, but doesn't count the offset. So at the time = 0 the PointZero is one, and at the end of animation the PointZero is not actually parent's {0, 0}.

Comment: did you try using CCMoveBy? I just checked, it works just like you need

Comment: Holy bananas, the reason why it didn't work is ```stopAllActions``` called later. I am editing old code. And don't know it very good yet. Sorry for silly questions. And thank you for patience and help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Holy bananas - need to remember that)))